# Initiate twilio flex chat using node.js

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat, twilio-flex

I am having difficulty getting twilio flex to show messages created using the API using node.js.

I am creating a channel, adding a member, creating a message on the channel using the member.

The flex dashboard shows the incoming chat request in the task list, I can answer the chat request but none of the messages I save to the channel are show.

The interesting thing is if I use the twilio-flex-webchat.min.js script and initiate a chat from a web page and then get the ChannelSid for that conversation (using https://chat.twilio.com/v2/Services/ISXXXX/Channels) I can use the APIs to create messages for this channel and they appear on the flex dashboard. But I need all this to work via node.js.

I compared the task, channel, reservation, member and message twilio objects both for chat conversations using the twilio-flex-webchat.min.js web library and the objects created by the node.js code. I cannot find any notable difference.

Does anybody have any insights?

Here is my code.

```
const accountSid = 'ACXXXXXXXXXX';
const authToken = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
const workspaceSid = 'WSXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx';
const workFlowSid = 'WWXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
const serviceSid = 'ISXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';


const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

(async () => {

    //create channel
    let channel = await client.chat.services(serviceSid)
        .channels
        .create({
            attributes: JSON.stringify({
                status: "ACTIVE",
                from: "Some Person",
                channel_type: "web"
            }),
            workflowSid: workFlowSid,
            taskChannel: 'chat',
            friendlyName: 'Flex WebChat',
            type: 'private'
        });

    //create a member in this channel
    let member = await client.chat.services(serviceSid)
        .channels(channel.sid)
        .members
        .create({ identity: 'WEB_CLIENT' });

    //post a message to this channel from the member
    let message = await client.chat.services(serviceSid)
        .channels(channel.sid)
        .messages.create({ body: 'This is a test message', to: channel.sid, from: 'WEB_CLIENT' });

    //create a task for my programable chat channel and associate the channel sid for my current conversation
    let task = await client.taskrouter.workspaces(workspaceSid)
        .tasks
        .create({
            attributes: JSON.stringify({
                channelSid: channel.sid,
                channelType: "web"
            }),
            workflowSid: workFlowSid,
            taskChannel: 'chat',
        });
})();
```

Thanks

Comment: HI Mike, did you get any where with this?

Answer (score 0):

Before adding a message and creating a Task, you need to create a proxy session, add the members as participants and then update the channel attributes:

```
    {
      "status": "ACTIVE",
      "forwarding": true,
      "twilioNumber": firstParticipant.proxyIdentifier,
      "serviceNumber": someIdentity,
      "from": from,
      "channel_type": "sms",
      "proxySession": session.sid
    }
```

Comment: Hi did you guys solve this? I have too gone through all of the ‘standard’ setup for web chat, and tried getting my chats initiated directly via programmable chat / iOS sdk to show up I flex. There doesn’t seem to be a straight forward way of doing this. Replicating what the web chat widget does locally is definitely a good start. I would have assumed though a lot of this config should be at the Twilio server side with web hooks and tasks etc?